# how to load menubar and submenu using jquery dynamically

Tags: jquery

How do I load the menubar and submenu using jQuery dynamically?

My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#ulSub").append('<li id="abc"><h5>Cancer information</h5><ul id="ulSub1">');     var ciid = $("#ulSub li").find("ul").attr("id");
$(ciid).append('<li><h5>What is cancer</h5></li></ul></li>'); }); 

<div class="dmenu"> <ul id="ulSub">  </ul> </div>
```

Why is this not appending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `.attr("id")` and it will work.

When doing `$(ciid)`, jQuery expects `ciid` to be a jQuery object.

**Working Code Snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#ulSub").append('<li id="abc"><h5>Cancer information</h5><ul id="ulSub1">');     
  var ciid = $("#ulSub li").find("ul");  // get jQuery object
  $(ciid).append('<li><h5>What is cancer</h5></li></ul></li>'); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="dmenu"> <ul id="ulSub">  </ul> </div>
```

Comment: do you have code to load menu and submenu through jquery...any sample

Comment: @SwapnilShinde That should be posted as another question here on StackOverflow. Post it and give me the link here so I can help you out.

Comment: hi i had posted one question plz answer me

Comment: @SwapnilShinde I have posted an answer for it with a working code snippet. Please check it.

Comment: i reached my question limit, shall i get code to loading menu and submenu using jquery all should dynamically